# Using JSON in ejs and node.js

Tags: json, node.js, ejs

Im pretty new to node and ejs, but making my way through. Having some trouble with correctly reading my JSON file into my ejs partial.

based on information i sourced from other similar questions here's what I have 
sample of my json. default contains a list of about 8 buttons details, but there would eventually be more then just that default list, hence it needs to remain but is pretty redundant at the moment.

```
 {
    "default":{
            "1":
            {
                "id":"alertmessages",
                "title":"Your Messages",
                "subtitle":"Tasks waiting for your attention",
                "image":"alert.png",
           }, 
            "2":
            {
                "id":"uploadr",
                "title":"Upload",
                "subtitle":"Upload",
                "image":"baskets.png",
            }       

    }

}
```

my node.js

```
var jsondata = JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync('./app/routes/dashboard/buttons.json', 'utf8'));

var content = {
    title: 'Dashboard',
    user: req.user,
    buttonsdata:jsondata
};
res.render('dashboard', content);
```

I think have a dashboard view which is pulling in an ejs partial that would generate some buttons/clickable objects based on information in the json

just trying to be able to read that data right now in that partial view a console log.

```
console.log("<%= buttonsdata.default.1.id %>")
```

however this error gives

```
missing ) after argument list in ..................while compiling ejs
```

this is the first time i am trying to read a json file also and I think the problem is the way I am console logging it in ejs, any advice on how to access particular piece of data from that file?

thanks

Comment: Little O.T. you can read the json directly via require('./app/routes/dashboard/buttons.json')

Comment: Have you tried `console.log( buttonsdata.default.1.id )` in your Node file? (Hint: it's not valid JS)

Comment: try with buttonsdata.default[1].id

Comment: more like: buttonsdata.default['1'].id because '1' & '2' are strings not integers

Comment: buttonsdata.default['1'].id worked. thanks Regarding why the long way of going about it, based on some detailed answers on another thread, it recommended using fs and to separate the require from the template to the back end.